# Display name of repository from Github Search API in React

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I am using Search API to find repositories from Github. I am currently able to search for repos but I want to display the name of the repo and information on the page. I am building the page in React. How do I get the data from the JSON file and add it to the page itself?

```
    let searchTerm;
const repositories = [];

 class SearchBox extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);

    }


    render() {
        return(
        <div>
            <form>
                <input type="text" className="searchbox"  ref={(input) => { this.searchBox = input; }}/>
                <button onClick={this.onClick}>Search</button>
            </form>
            <div className="foundRepo">{this.props.name}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }

    onClick(event) {

   searchTerm = this.searchBox.value;
   let endpoint = 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?sort=stars&order=desc&q=' + searchTerm;
   console.log(searchTerm);
        fetch(endpoint)
    .then(blob => blob.json())
    .then(data => repositories.push(...data));
    event.preventDefault();


    }
}
```

Both react and using APIs are quite new to me so the code might be a bit messy but it does work. Just need some help with how to access the data. thanks.

Comment: An answer would be great but I would also really appreciate an explanation or links to good explanations so I can understand what I do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the response data in component state, and loop over it with a `.map` to display it. You should read about [how component state works](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

```
let searchTerm;

class SearchBox extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
        this.state = { repositories: [] };
    }


    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <form>
                <input type="text" className="searchbox"  ref={(input) => { this.searchBox = input; }}/>
                <button onClick={this.onClick}>Search</button>
                </form>
                <div className="foundRepo">{this.props.name}</div>
                <h2>Repositories</h2>
                <ul>
                { this.state.repositories.map( ( item, index ) => (
                    <li key={ index }>
                        { item.name }
                    </li>
                )) }
                </ul>
            </div>
            );
    }

    onClick(event) {

        searchTerm = this.searchBox.value;
        let endpoint = 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?sort=stars&order=desc&q=' + searchTerm;
        console.log(searchTerm);
        fetch(endpoint)
            .then(blob => blob.json())
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({ repositories: response.items });
            });
        event.preventDefault();

    }
}
```

Comment: I get an error message in the console saying Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you! you're a lifesaver!

Comment: I wrote this a while ago for Flux, but it may be relevant here to helping understand how data flows through React http://blog.andrewray.me/flux-for-stupid-people/ (no offense!)